# MySQL connection failure in talend

Tags: mysql, talend

MySQL - Talend Test connection is throwing an error, "Connection Failure. You must change the Database Settings."

As shown in below image:

[image]

Comment: please expose more error details. your screenshot shows only one part of exception

Comment: You can check few things as an initial diagnosis like hostname, username/password or whether Mysql server is up